# Get network utilization from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, network-adapter

In the Windows task manager there is a handy network tab which shows the link speed and network utilization (in percentage of available bandwidth) for connected network adapters:

[image: Task Manager Screenshot]

Is there a way to get this information through the command line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171336/how-do-i-monitor-network-traffic-on-windows-from-the-command-line perhaps?

Comment: @Sam1370 I did take a look at that question earlier. It requires a third party tool.

Comment: Yes, but reposting the question again here doesn't help much either

Comment: It's a different question. I am asking for network utilization - how much of the bandwidth is being used. He is asking for network speeds.

Comment: It is not clear from the question and comments if your only requirement is being a Command line tool, or also avoiding third-party tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a (large?) number of command line options that give information on network usage.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171336/how-do-i-monitor-network-traffic-on-windows-from-the-command-line) deals with that, and answers there have a significant overlap with the present OP.
Many of them do not provide percentage bandwidth usage, as asked in the OP.

1. The option with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) was given above.
2. [`typeperf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf) (Windows native) is also relevant, with a few options.
   `typeperf -q "Network Interface"` lists all the objects.
   Then, use `typeperf "\Network Interface(*)\...` with the following options:

   ```
   \Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth
   \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Sent/sec
   ```

   Note that the formula is `((Total Bytes/Sec * 8)/current bandwidth) * 100`.
   Other useful options:

   ```
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received Unicast/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received Non-Unicast/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received Discarded
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received Errors
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Received Unknown
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Sent Unicast/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Sent Non-Unicast/sec
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Outbound Discarded
   \Network Interface(*)\Packets Outbound Errors
   \Network Interface(*)\Output Queue Length
   \Network Interface(*)\Offloaded Connections
   ```

   You can use flag `-sc <samples>` (Specifies the number of samples to collect. The default is to collect data until CTRL+C is pressed), see [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf).

   Flag `-o <filename>` (Specifies the path for the output file, or the SQL database. The default is STDOUT (written to the command window).) may also be useful.
3. An interesting script, which may be customized to give various pieces of information and format it, is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332523/2707864).

Comment: The `typeperf`command does not end until you press `Ctrl + C` or close the command prompt. I need this command so I get get network utilization from a Java program. Is there a way I can stop the `typeperf`command from my Java program? Also, could you explain the command output? I do not understand what the different numbers represent: http://oneclickpaste.com/3833/

Comment: @CardinalSystem - I am not sure this will work, but I guess you need to "java inject keyboard presses" (this is what I searched for) from your parent Java program.
E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585000/inject-a-keystroke-in-java
Otherwise, it seems you can use it with flag `-sc <samples>` (Specifies the number of samples to collect. The default is to collect data until CTRL+C is pressed).

Comment: @CardinalSystem You should head over to [so] and ask the question you really want: "How do I get Windows network usage from Java?". You're much better off using a proper API (likely a Win32 API via JNA) than trying to parse command-line output. It'll be much (*much*) faster and won't break when someone changes the unguaranteed output  text format (or localises it for a different language).

Comment: @Bob - I generally agree with you (asking the question one really wants). But one may be interested in accomplishing several things at a time, so perhaps the OP needs this. This happened to me before.
At any rate, it is good to encourage OPs to guiding answerers as precisely as possible.

Comment: @sancho.s Oh, I have nothing against this question as it is. But once you try to extend it to "...so I can call and parse it from Java", it's quite a different question - and there are many much better answers that are available for *that* question this one can't address. I'm not saying change or move this question, but rather ask a new one (on the appropriate site) for better answers to the other question.

Comment: @Bob - Agreed! In addition, the question becomes a moving target.

Comment: @CardinalSystem - Besides having assigned the bounty and accepted the answer, could you make it work? It would be interesting if you also post feedback.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without installing anything through PowerShell.

You can see the Total Speed and name of each adapter using:

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

You can then take the name and put in into unique id and see the amount on incoming traffic with:

```
Get-Counter "\Network Interface(<unique id>)\Bytes Received/sec"
```

If you want outgoing or total traffic, use:

```
Get-Counter "\Network Interface(<unique id>)\Bytes Sent/sec"
Get-Counter "\Network Interface(<unique id>)\Bytes Total/sec"
```

You can also measure usage over time by adding something like:

```
-SampleInterval 3 -MaxSamples 5
```

See the [help page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1) for more info.

Comment: "take the name and put it in to the unique ID..." I entered `Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter` and it didn't work. Here's the error message: 
http://oneclickpaste.com/3830/

Comment: You need quotes around the adapter name as it has spaces

Comment: Try `Get-Counter "\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/sec"` and you will see what the valid entries are.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to collect stats:

```
tshark -z <statistics>
```

You can use [`netstat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat):

```
netstat -a -n
```

Or [`typeperf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf):

```
typeperf "Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth"
typeperf "Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec"
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer! I need to see if there is a way to end the `typeperf` command without pressing `Ctrl + C`. Third-party tools will not work in my situation (unless they are simple single file executables). I will consider you for the bounty when it is time to accept an answer. +1