# How can I show the current network transfer speed on Windows?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, powershell, internet-speed

I am looking for a way to show me an approximate current network transfer rate (incoming and outgoing) over LAN and WLAN.

I am currently struggling with internet speeds (they can go from normal 100 Mbit/s to measely 5 Mbit/s in a matter of seconds) and constantly running speedtest (or similar services) during regular internet use will only make my situation worse. Yes, this is ISP issue they are aware of, but it will take some time to fix and I need an indicator of my current speed for now.
I am using Windows 10 version 1909 (build 18363.476).

I am not even sure if this is possible (thus my question). Can I do that, and if so, how? Can it be done with a PowerShell command?

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/q/1430230/48078

Comment: It appears what you actually want to know is the _currently usable_ line speed. However, you can only get this value by testing. Otherwise, you can only see the bandwidth _in use_, which will probably be a lot less unless you’re downloading something.

Comment: I think I will actually go with Task Manager's built-in network throughput indicator. This is pretty much what I was looking for except for maybe convenience (I can't really monitor other parameters of my PC), but that will do for now.

Comment: @slhck I used your second suggestion as a possible answer, but there still might other ways to go about it. Also, network gadgets (or gadgets in general) no longer work in Windows 10 natively (but thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: @DanielB I was actually looking exactly for throughput indicator since I already use at least 5 Mbits/s incoming (but through browser and other programs).

Answer (score 0):

For now, I will go with Task Manager's throughput indicator, but I am still looking for other suggestions that might be more convenient.

[Task Manager's network throughput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkC43.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HWiNFO64 to get the required information and Rainmeter to always display it on your desktop. A little bit of a learning curve, but it might worth it.

Comment: Ok, I will give both a try.

Comment: You can also use HWiNFO64 to display the information in the taskbar if you would prefer it this way.